# Closed question

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

It is rather strange, that question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9993/the-unreasonable-effectiveness-of-mathematics-in-physics that practically reproduces title of talk of (future - 4 years after the talk) Nobel Prize winner, Eugene Wigner  http://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/MathDrama/reading/Wigner.html caused such a negative reaction (immediately closed and -3 votes – so it is not only a moderator opinion). Beside that, it was printed in a serious and refereed journal. Poincare, Feynman, et. al. also wrote deep works about that. The question itself is only couple of lines long and practically only clarifies title, so some additional flaws most likely could not be inserted there.

Comment: -1 how does being a title of a talk being a nobel prize winner actually make any difference to the validity of the question?

Answer (score 2):

This question is discussion-provoking, and such are prohibited because they don't fit the flow of this site. You are free to use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/physics) to discuss about the matter of the question.

Comment: Just for clarification, the question is not mine...

Comment: @Alex Good point =)

Comment: Why is the question now deleted, I wanted to have a look at it since I have not seen it before.

Comment: Because this is an automatically enforced fate of old closed questions.

Comment: @mbq can it be undeleted since this meta question asks about it? Do closed question that have upvotes and/or answers get deleted too? That would be really worrysome ... Now I vaguely remember to have seen that question, and I think it should not have been deleted. If I am correct it was an interesting one asking why physics is described so good by mathematics or something.

Comment: @Dilation Here are the contents of that Q: *Why is physics so mathematical? Why does mathematics describe reality so well? There doesn't appear to be any a priori reason why this should be so. Is this idle philosophical speculation?*

Comment: And again, the issue is not whether it is a valid problem or not, rather can it be answered in a single post or is it an invitation to a lengthy discussion.

Comment: @mbq yeah, maybe I confused it with another similar one I have seen, which had some very good, interesting, and serious answers from the physicists here. For the one I mean it would be a pity if it were deleted.